# How to force the back button to show on title bar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, freshmvvm

Here's the scenario:

I'm working with **Xamarin** forms and using **FreshMVVM**.

My main screen is a **FreshTabbedFONavigationContainer**, one of the tabs navigate deeper into other pages while the others don't. If I'm in one of those deeper pages and do:

```
CoreMethods.PushNewNavigationServiceModal(...)
```

the next navigation page is added to the stack and the back button appears and works fine.

But if I call the same method from a root page in my main tabs page, the back button doesn't appear. I'm calling the same method, the same way, with the same argument types. I've even tried the same arguments.

Why would it work from a deeper **FreshBasePageModel** and not from the first **FreshBasePageModel** in a **FreshTabbedFONavigationContainer**? I've tried **FreshTabbedNavigationContainer** too and it made no difference.

Also, is there a way to force the back button to show and manage its behavior?

Comment: Tell us more about CoreMethods.PushNewNavigationServiceModal(...) is this a static method or instance method?

Comment: static method from FreshMVVM

Comment: Set a break point on entry to that method.  Is it called when you expect?

Comment: Yes. Everything runs the same way, line by line in all methods.

Comment: I believe it's something related to UWP. Somehow it's considering to be still on the first page because I pushed another navigation from a navigation container first page.

Comment: Ok. The same is happening to the ios version.

Comment: Could you provide more code that calls the push method from root page ?

Comment: Have you tried Presenting the view controller instead? and then enabling the navigation bar in the ViewDidLoad method of the ViewController that your presenting.

Comment: I've no view controller. I'm working with Xamarin Forms FreshMVVM. And the problem is definitely not in my code, it's either in Xamarin Forms or FreshMVVM. So either I force it somehow, or wait for them to fix it. The second option is not probable.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No. I created an issue at the FreshMvvm github page but the developer doesn't seem to care for FreshMvvm issues. You may try to push him: https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/issues/168#issuecomment-313771962

Comment: This is still an issue w/ freshMvvm in 2020, I will be ditching FreshMvvm as soon as possible.

Comment: @jon.nicholssoftware.com I ditched xamarin a long time ago man. I'm with Flutter now. Not great too, but much much more active development and community.